# Intermediate size between \textstyle and \displaystyle

Tags: fractions, displaystyle

I am looking for a way to write equations in a paragraph that are bigger than the `\textstyle` option but smaller than the `\displaystyle` option. The screenshot below explains what I'm talking about.

[image]

The above example is with a fraction but I want to be able to find an intermediate size for any mathematical object (`\sum`, `\bigcup`, `\bigcap`, ...)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please provide a small test document that produces the output shown, but probably you can use `{\large$\frac{PQ}{d_2}$}`

Comment: I'd consider to slash the fraction, i.e. to use `PQ/d_2` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`\large` textstyle may be what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaa
$\frac{PQ}{d_2}$
bbb
$\displaystyle\frac{PQ}{d_2}$
ccc
{\large$\frac{PQ}{d_2}$}
dddd

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to do this in say an equation? I usually use {\textstyle\frac{}{}} to create a small \frac but would be convenient if I could find some size between \textstyle and \displaystyle